# Coverting array of strings into JSONString in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, string, swift

I have an array of strings that contains image names and I want to convert it into JSON String to be sent to server. I have an array that contains names such as (abc.jpg, def.jpg, ghi.jpg). I'm using the following code to convert this array into JSONString so I have this format of string ["abc.jpg", "def.jpg", "ghi.jpg"], with double quotes and square bracket

```
do {
   self.licenseImageNameArrayJSONString = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self.deletedLicenseImages, options: [])
   }
   catch let error as NSError {
     print(error.description)
   }
}
```

But I can't achieve the desired result, instead on my HTTP debugger it shows string like <5b0a2020 22353665 64326435 65653539 30622e6a 7067220a 5d>. I don't want it in this format. My String is array string is declared as:

> var deletedLicenseImages = String

Can anyone please help me on how can I convert

> (abc.jpg, def.jpg, ghi.jpg)

into

> ["abc.jpg", "def.jpg", "ghi.jpg"]

to send to server for processing? Thanks!

Comment: `I have an array that contains names such as (abc.jpg, def.jpg, ghi.jpg)`, Doesn't that mean you already have an array: `["abc.jpg", "def.jpg", "ghi.jpg"]`? Please show us your actual code of your array to prevent confusion.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I think I was changing into JSON string which is wrong, there's no need for this, just directly send the array to server side. Thanks a lot!

Comment: JSON is a binary format. If you want to convert it to a string, just use `NSString` initializer with UTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't receive design result from server then try using NSDictionary instead of NSArray.

let arrValue:NSArray = NSArray(objects: "array of images")

let arrKEY:NSArray= NSArray (objects: "KEY1")

let objDict = NSMutableDictionary(objects: arrValue as [AnyObject], forKeys: arrKey as! [NSCopying])

then pass objDict to your server

Answer (score -1):

You actually didn't need to convert you array string but just the array as a string to server

It will solve ur issue